# How do you use Chinese in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, koma-script, context, typography, chinese

This is driving me nuts.

I need to find a way to have use Chinese characters in LuaLaTeX with the KOMA-script document format, however all the options for typesetting Chinese either force me to use a chinese document format or use a Japanese document format. I think I can move to XeTeX but i don't know if it's neccessary. I want to try ConTeXt but the name is counterproductive and it's documentation are horrible.

Here's the text i wanted to typeset:

```
\title{
    漢文文範\\
    Hán văn văn phạm 
}
\subtitle{
    使用詞彙與格讀漢越\\
    sử dụng từ vựng và cách đọc Hán Việt
}
\author{
    武克富強\\
    Võ Khắc Phú Cường
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code. A minimal document with some Chinese content. I have no idea how to input Chinese, even if I see it, but I've been known to typeset it. You are perhaps looking for `polyglossia`? I have no idea what's wrong with ConTeXt's name but please decide which format and engine you want to use!

Comment: I'm asking which is the best way to display chinese using lualatex.

Comment: So please edit your question, provide code for a minimal document with some Chinese content and make it clear you want to use LuaLaTeX. Saying you're willing to switch to XeLaTeX is fine, if that's true, but saying you really want to use ConTeXt makes this a different question. ConTeXt is a different format. It is not LaTeX.

Comment: Your sample code suggests that you need to be able to typeset both Vietnamese and Chinese text. Is this correct? And, are you interested in Traditional Chinese or Simplified Chinese glyphs?

Comment: Yes, Traditional Chinese only.

Comment: @AdrikIvanov does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEDq4.png) look acceptable? I can't read either of the languages you are using, but I have found a way to reach the stage I have shown (with XeLaTeX). If you think this is good, then I will post it as an answer.

Comment: yes, please post them

Comment: Is the text above the only text in Chinese?

Comment: well there's more but I want to have chinese and Vietnamese fonts avaliable to use in a document.

Comment: You should ping people with @name. The question is if you need more than simply font support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ctex` bundle which is developed for typesetting CJK characters. According to different compilation engines, `ctex` will automatically choose different methods to support Chinese typesetting from the lower-level (For `lualatex` case, it depends on LuaTeX-ja). Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ctex}
\title{
    漢文文範\\
    Hán văn văn phạm 
}
\subtitle{
    使用詞彙與格讀漢越\\
    sử dụng từ vựng và cách đọc Hán Việt
}
\author{
    武克富強\\
    Võ Khắc Phú Cường
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to use, say, [Noto Serif TC](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif+TC) font, then install that font in your machine and use `\setCJKmainfont` to select it:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont = NotoSerifTC-Bold]{NotoSerifTC-Regular}
\title{
    漢文文範\\
    Hán văn văn phạm 
}
\subtitle{
    使用詞彙與格讀漢越\\
    sử dụng từ vựng và cách đọc Hán Việt
}
\author{
    武克富強\\
    Võ Khắc Phú Cường
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I change the font? IDK Chinese so i can't read the documentation.

Comment: @AdrikIvanov What’s your operating system? macOS or windows?

Comment: Windows, but perferably without need for a change to the operating system @Stephen

Comment: @AdrikIvanov What chinese font do you need to use?

Comment: some personal font that is based on Noto Serif CJK. But why do you ask? Just put Noto Serif CJK.

Comment: See the updated version@AdrikIvanov

Answer (score 5):

If you need it only for short text or a few words you can define for lualatex a fallback font, see the luaotfload documentation for details. For more sophisticated setups check babel which too offers various commands to define a fallback font and language switch based on script.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua
 {luaotfload.add_fallback
   ("JPfallback",
     {"Noto Sans CJK JP:mode=harf;"}
   )
 }

\setmainfont{Arial}[RawFeature={fallback=JPfallback}]
\setsansfont{Arial}[RawFeature={fallback=JPfallback}]
\title{
  漢文文範\\
  Hán văn văn phạm 
}
\subtitle{
  使用詞彙與格讀漢越\\
  sử dụng từ vựng và cách đọc Hán Việt
}
\author{
  武克富強\\
  Võ Khắc Phú Cường
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yet another option, this time with `babel` (see the page on [Chinese](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-chinese.html) in the `babel` site for further info).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}{IPAexMincho}
\babelfont[chinese]{sf}{IPAexGothic}

\title{
    漢文文範\\
    Hán văn văn phạm 
}
\subtitle{
    使用詞彙與格讀漢越\\
    sử dụng từ vựng và cách đọc Hán Việt
}
\author{
    武克富強\\
    Võ Khắc Phú Cường
}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't read either of the languages you are using, neither do I know good fonts for them, but I used KokoroMinchoutai for Chinese and the default Latin Modern for Vietnamese in this document. I have compiled it with XeLaTeX. Feel free to change it to some other fonts you know.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\chinesefont}{KokoroMinchoutai}
\usepackage[Chinese,Latin]{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\normalfont}{}
\setTransitionsForChinese{\chinesefont}{}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\normalfont}{}
\title{
  漢文文範\\
  Hán văn văn phạm 
}
\subtitle{
  使用詞彙與格讀漢越\\
  sử dụng từ vựng và cách đọc Hán Việt
}
\author{
  武克富強\\
  Võ Khắc Phú Cường
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

To typeset chinese with ConTeXt you can use the font fallback mechanism to add missing characters to the main font. The example below combines the regular Noto font with the CJK Noto font.

To enable line breaking for chinese text you need the `\setscript` command.

```
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [rm] [Noto Serif CJK TC]     [preset=range:chinese]
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [ss] [Noto Sans CJK TC]      [preset=range:chinese]
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [tt] [Noto Sans Mono CJK TC] [preset=range:chinese]

\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm]        [Noto Serif]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss]        [Noto Sans]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [tt]        [Noto Sans Mono]
\definetypeface   [mainface] [mm] [math] [stixtwo]

\setupbodyfont [mainface]

\mainlanguage [chinese]

\setscript [hanzi]

\starttext

\startalignment[middle]
  \startfont[Sans sa 3]\setupinterlinespace
    漢文文範\par
    Hán văn văn phạm\par
  \stopfont
  \blank
  \startfont[Sans sa 2]\setupinterlinespace
    使用詞彙與格讀漢越\par
    sử dụng từ vựng và cách đọc Hán Việt\par
  \stopfont
  \blank
  \startfont[Serif sa 2]\setupinterlinespace
    武克富強\par
    Võ Khắc Phú Cường\par
    \blank
    \currentdate
  \stopfont
\stopalignment

\stoptext
```

[image]